# Getting ERROR unexpected token: CloverPublisher in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, clover

Here i have generated Clover test report(Clover.xml) in my build server and i have installed the clover plugin in Jenkins to display unit test results.

My Jenkinsfile code is:

```
    pipeline{
        agent{ 
            label 'DukE'
        }
      stages{
            stage ('Checkout-Update Code From SVN') {
                steps{
                     //My steps
                }
            }
       }
        post {
            always {
                    $class: 'CloverPublisher',
                    cloverReportDir: '/DIR',
                    cloverReportFileName: 'clover.xml',
                    healthyTarget: [methodCoverage: 70, conditionalCoverage: 60, statementCoverage: 60],
                    unhealthyTarget: [methodCoverage: 50, conditionalCoverage: 50, statementCoverage: 50],
                    failingTarget: [methodCoverage: 0, conditionalCoverage: 0, statementCoverage: 0]
            }
        }
}
```

I'm getting following error

```
unexpected token: CloverPublisher @ line 65, column 13.
$class: 'CloverPublisher',
```

Can any one please help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: Just guessing: would it work to remove the `$` in front of `class`?

Comment: No its not working

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the clover statements within `step([])` as follows:

```
always {
    step([
        $class: 'CloverPublisher',
        cloverReportDir: 'coverage',
        cloverReportFileName: 'clover.xml',
        healthyTarget: [methodCoverage: 70, conditionalCoverage: 80, statementCoverage: 80], // optional, default is: method=70, conditional=80, statement=80
        unhealthyTarget: [methodCoverage: 50, conditionalCoverage: 50, statementCoverage: 50], // optional, default is none
        failingTarget: [methodCoverage: 0, conditionalCoverage: 0, statementCoverage: 0]     // optional, default is none
  ])
}
```

See the official docs - https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Clover+Plugin > Configuring with Jenkins Workflow/Pipeline jobs